# PHPmailer will not send emails to my gmail account

Tags: php, email

I'm using this code to try and get PHPmailer to send emails to people who use my website as gmail has blocked me from using php mail() apparently. However, It returns the error `Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: myemail@gmail.com`

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'myhost';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'site email';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'site email';
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Where are you sending this from?

Comment: A php file on my server, `test.php` @FreshPrinceOfSO

Comment: No. A local server, a web host? Do you have SMTP installed?

Comment: Have you tried other email addresses?

Comment: I'm on paid hosting and I've no idea if smtp is installed

Comment: Maybe your host has disabled mailing to `gmail`?

Answer (score 0):

mail($to, $subject,$message, $headers, "-fSENDEREMAILID");

try to add -f before the sender email id in the mail function and it works i guess